# Context in nextjs is undefined (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am creating an authentication for every route and I wanted to have the value of the user available in every route, that's why I used context.

I made a layout component which I import in the app right after the context like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.pathname == '/' || router.pathname == '/_error') {
      router.push('/login')
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Here's my layout component:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const {loggedInUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.pathname == '/' || router.pathname == '/_error') {
      ...
    }
  }, [])

  return <div>{children}</div>
}

export default Layout
```

Here's my context:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext()

function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [loggedInUser, setUserLoggedIn] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      if (!currentUser) {
        setUserLoggedIn(currentUser)
      } else {
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{
    loggedInUser,
    setUserLoggedIn
  }}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default AuthProvider
```

When I try to enter a route I get this error
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loggedInUser' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.`

I hope you can help me!

Comment: `useEffect()` runs after the component is mounted, so on the initial mount you have `loggedInUser` as undefined. Is this intentional?

Comment: Oh that was the problem thank you! I had resolved it making a new component

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrap the root component.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import AuthContext from "./context/AuthContext";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContext> // your context <----------------
      <App /> // wrap the root component
    </AuthContext> // your context  <----------------
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  He's wrapped the component in which he's accessing the context.  It need not be the root. -1